# женщина - его жена

Tags: приложение

На берегу меня ждали Севрюки: худой человек в сапогах и чесучовом пиджаке – хозяин поместья, невысокая молодая женщина – его жена и студент – ее брат.
•
•   Распространенные приложения имеются при каждом из трех однородных членах (членов ?) - хозяин поместья, его жена и ее брат, относящиеся к определяемым сочетаниям и слову человек в сапогах и чесучовом пиджаке, невысокая молодая женщина и студент. По отношению к подлежащему Севрюки это однородные члены при обобщающем слове.

Это из работы о приложениях в "Повести о жизни" Паустовского.

Почему приложение *его жена* справа не отделяется тире, как и слева?

Например, у Горького: *Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её.*

после приложения *жертвах жизни* тире не ставится, так как обозначает более конкретное значение.

•   На террасе я увидел бабушку, Николая Кузьмича — соседа по квартире, сестру Нину с двумя подругами.

Здесь после приложения *соседа по квартире* второе тире опускается для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения.

Оба последних случая не подходят к первому, и, казалось бы, по общему правилу нужно поставить тире:

На берегу меня ждали Севрюки: худой человек в сапогах и чесучовом пиджаке – хозяин поместья, невысокая молодая женщина – его жена – и студент – ее брат.

Но три тире многовато, лучше заменить заменить скобками:

На берегу меня ждали Севрюки: худой человек в сапогах и чесучовом пиджаке – хозяин поместья, невысокая молодая женщина (его жена) и студент – ее брат.

У Розенталя следующее правило:

Второе тире опускается:
1)      если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая, например: Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой – акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров;
2)      если приложением выражается более конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет более общее значение, например: На встрече лидеров стран – участниц Содружества Независимых Государств рассматривались актуальные проблемы экономического развития;
3)      если в подобной конструкции приложение предшествует определяемому слову, например: Самый лживый, лицемерный и самый влиятельный из всех «учителей жизни» – церковь, проповедуя «любовь к ближнему как к самому себе», в прошлом жгла десятки тысяч людей на кострах, благословляла «религиозные» войны (Горький); Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны – спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд (Из газет);
а)      для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения, например: За столом сидели хозяйка дома, ее сестра – подруга моей жены, двое незнакомых мне лиц, моя жена и я. Второе тире в этих случаях не ставится; ср.: Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях – жертвах жизни и о людях – владыках ее (Горький);
б)      для отделения препозитивных (стоящих впереди) однородных приложений от определяемого слова, например: Автор замечательных произведений для детей, блестящий переводчик, поэт и драматург – Маршак занял видное место в отечественной литературе;
в)      в конструкциях типа: Мефистофель – Шаляпин был неподражаем. Ср.: Эрнани – Горев плох, как сапожник (из письма А.П. Чехова).

Answer (score 4):

На берегу меня ждали Севрюки: худой человек в сапогах и чесучовом пиджаке – хозяин поместья, невысокая молодая женщина – его жена и студент – ее брат.

Одно тире ставится **при тесной связи** распространенного приложения с определяемым существительным. Такое тире иногда называют **тире-дефисом**, так как произносится словосочетание без паузы, как при дефисном написании, сравнить: женщина-жена, студент-брат (хотя без определения такие сочетания не используются).

Выбор может быть авторским, например: Ловили рыбу бреднем –  маленьким неводом –  да вершами-ловушками. Здесь выбрано два тире, вставочная интонация, **добавочное значение приложения**, в то же время одно тире также возможно (тогда произношение без паузы, обозначение тесной связи).